# Java: on the cost of calling Runtime.freeMemory(), Runtime.totalMemory() and Runtime.maxMemory()

Tags: java, performance, memory, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a `Map` in memory that stores my objects. I'd like to flush to memory when I'm running out of memory. I'm doing this right now:

```
void add(K key, V value) {
    if (underPressure()) {
        flush(innerMap);
    }
    innerMap.add(k, v);
}

boolean underPressure() {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
    long freeMemory = rt.freeMemory();

    return (double) freeMemory / maxMemory < threshold;
}
```

As `underPressure()` is called at each insert, how expensive is it? To my understanding, as it's an approximation, it should be somehow *cached* by the jvm, but does anybody know more about this for real?

Comment: Its probably different on difference machines.  How expensive is it on your machine?  You could also test `return freememory < maxMemory * threshold;` as multiplication is slightly faster than division.

Comment: Note: freeMemory only tells you how much memory you have before you need to perform a GC. It doesn't tell you how much would be free after a GC.

Comment: Personally I would go `final boolean underPressure()` or someone will subclass and override the method with a rap with really bad lyrics. Then whenever someone sees that method signature, if they're not over a certain age they'll identify it with Vanilla Ice's version and you'll be biting the dust. :-(

Comment: On my PC it takes 72 ns on average.

Comment: Yep, on my machine it's about 50 times slower than `new ArrayList<String>()`

Comment: Isn't that what garbage collection supposed to do for you if you use Weak keys and WeakHashMaps?

Comment: @Bill K you're totally missing the point. It's not about optimization, is about storing data to disk because it might or might not fit in memory. I don't see the premature optimization nor the optimization at all in this, just a strategy. And in order to put in practice you need a moment WHEN to do it. As simple as that.

Comment: @mazaneicha no, that's different. That would free the memory when no other object is present, I need a strategy for knowing WHEN/IF to flush to disk because I finished the heap.

Comment: @Marcorossi You are absolutely right--When I saw you mention "freeMemory" my brain thought you were calling "gc" to force garbage collection.  I can tell you that they are very expensive calls and that it may be possible to use the reference classes to do the same thing.  I'll delete my other comment.

Answer (score 5):

Since Java 7 there is no need to poll the free memory any more. It is possible to register for a garbage collection event. See this post: http://www.fasterj.com/articles/gcnotifs.shtml

So the best way I can think of, is to check the free memory after the garbage collection and then free additional space, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [JMXBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html) to do this.  It was designed to simplify this kind of operations..

From the docs...

> The API provides access to information such as:
>
> ```
> Number of classes loaded and threads running
> Virtual machine uptime, system properties, and JVM input arguments
> Thread state, thread contention statistics, and stack trace of live threads
> Memory consumption
> Garbage collection statistics
> Low memory detection
> On-demand deadlock detection
> Operating system information
> ```

Specifically see the example code in [MemoryPoolMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryPoolMXBean.html)

Comment: Sounds like the right place to look at. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly answering your question but as already said in the comments *freeMemory* counts the free memory rather than the memory that would be available after a GC, thus if you call *freeMemory* just before the GC runs you may think you are reaching your "underPressure" limit but you could as well have plenty of free memory after the next GC run.

Another approach may be to create a softly reachable object and to check if it was claimed by the GC:

something like:

```
SoftReference<Object> sr = new SoftReference<Object>(new Object(),new ReferenceQueue<Object>());
public boolean underPressure(){
    if (sr.isEnqueued()) {
        // recreate object to monitor
        sr = new SoftReference<Object>(new Object(),new ReferenceQueue<Object>());
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: question: why using the ReferenceQueue? Isn't it enough to sr.get() == null to check whether there's pressure (and recreate sr in that case as well)?